# Django migration error,auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_01ab375a_uniq duplicated key

Tags: python, django

I am trying to migrate my module to PostgresSQL but when I do I got an error that teling me the key unique "auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_01ab375a_uniq" is duplicated .
the key  (content_type_id, codename)=(1,view_arrets) are existed .
The code somehow create a duplicates views .
my modules are :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class ProfilsHoraires(models.Model):
    P_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_profil = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=120)
    d_p_1 = models.TimeField()
    f_p_1 = models.TimeField()
    d_p_2 = models.TimeField()
    f_p_2 = models.TimeField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profilsHoraires'
        ordering = ['P_id']
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles-edit", kwargs={"P_id": self.P_id})
class categorie(models.Model):
     Categorie = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20, blank=True)
     class Meta:
         db_table = 'categorie'
         ordering = ['Categorie']
     def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("categorie-edit", kwargs={"id": self.Categorie})
class Destination(models.Model):
    destinationNom=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=90, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'disination'
        ordering = ['destinationNom']
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("destination-edit", kwargs={"id": self.destinationNom})

class Collaborateurs(models.Model):
    mle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longtitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    libele_dest = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    profil = models.ForeignKey(ProfilsHoraires, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'collaborateurs'
        ordering = ['mle']
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("collabs-edit", kwargs={"mle": self.mle})

class Vehicules(models.Model):
    V_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    allocation= models.FloatField(null=False)
    capacite = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vehicules'
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.type
    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("vehicules-edit", kwargs={"V_id": self.V_id})

class LieuxAffet(models.Model):
    id_lieu = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_ville = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    libelle_lieu = models.TextField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longtitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    libelle_dest = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'lieux_affet'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("lieux-edit", kwargs={"id_lieu": self.id_lieu})

class Arrets(models.Model):
    id_arret = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_lieu_affet = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    id_dest = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    libelle_arret = models.TextField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    longtitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
    id_suiv = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Arrets'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("arrtes-edit", kwargs={"id_arret": self.id_arret})
```

Comment: What are you running to generate that error?

Comment: I tried to migrate my modules to my database

Comment: are you add the unique constraints newly? Then if the existing records are not unique migration will raise error.  create a script/write sql qurey to make the records unique..then migrate

Comment: I did,but it always create duplicated view,even when I tried to delete my db but the error is still remain.

Comment: why blank=True in primary key?

Comment: are you creating any custom permissions/ using django's permission system..check the code related to it.

Comment: check the following link:https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission/issues/55

Comment: it dosn't work Jisson